# Update one column in CSV File C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I want to update one column (3rd column) based on condition from database in CSV File.
Want to Remove 100, and replace it with ,, for the Employees with Dept 1500 in CSV File

Database table:

```
EmpID DeptID

100 1500

101 1300

102 1500
```

CSV File as shown like below:

```
EmpID,EmpName,Score,Grade1,Grade2,Grade3
100,emp1,100,A1,A3
101,emp2,250,A1,A5,A2
102,emp3,100,A1
```

Result should be like this:

```
100,emp1,,A1,A3
101,emp2,250,A1,A5,A2
102,emp3,,A1
```

First thing, I am unable to replace the values in third column, see the code below:

```
string file1 = @"F:\test.csv"; string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1);
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file1);    
foreach(string s in lines) { 
    sw.WriteLine(s.Replace("100", ""));    
}    
sw.Close();
```

If i give the below line in foreach loop:

```
sw.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, s.Split(',')[2], m => s.Split(',')[2].ToString().Replace("100", "")));
```

It is replacing all the values from 100 to empty string.

Can you please tell me how to replace the value in the 3rd column?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lines = new string[10];
var splitLines = lines.Select(l => l.Split(','));
foreach (var splitLine in splitLines)
{
    if (splitLine[2] == "100")
    {
        splitLine[2] = "0";
    }
    var line = string.Join(",", splitLine);

    // And then do what you wish with the line.
}
```