# Editing/Saving a row in a CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

After following this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100139/update-one-column-in-csv-file-c-sharp) I am able to create
the new row but my question is how do 
I save or write the new line to the file?

I tried 'StreamWriter' but it only writes the newly
created line.

Any suggestions please?

Here is my code so far:

```
string path = @"C:/CSV.txt";

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

var splitlines = lines.Select(l => l.Split(','));

foreach (var line in splitlines)
{
   if(line[1].Contains("34"))
   {                                        
     line[1] = "100";
     var newline = string.Join(",", line);
     StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(path);    
     sr.WriteLine(newline);
     sr.Close();                                      
   }
 }
```

Comment: I don't see *anything* being written or printed.

Comment: Why the down vote? Okay I forgot to add the 'StreamWriter' line in the above code block (which I have now updated). But as mentioned in my post I tried StreamWriter and was only able to write the new line to the file. Whereas I had forgotten that the array list or a better way by using List<string> would have to updated and rewritten to the file which Zarathos solution rectified.

Comment: The (now removed) down-vote was for missing code. However, considering that "contains" is only sometimes true and therefore `WriteLine` is only sometime executed should hardly be surprising .. also, it is invalid to write to a Closed stream.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is your solution using `StreamReader` class:

```
String path = @"C:\CSV.txt";
List<String> lines = new List<String>();

if (File.Exists(path));
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(","))
            {
                String[] split = line.Split(',');

                if (split[1].Contains("34"))
                {
                    split[1] = "100";
                    line = String.Join(",", split);
                }
            }

            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
    {
        foreach (String line in lines)
            writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

If you want to overwrite the file, use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) StreamWriter constructor with `append = false`.

Comment: Excellent solution Zarathos. Wasn't aware of the StreamWriter constructor. But now I know :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe somthing like this, you probably will need to clean it up and add some error handling, but it does the job

```
    string path = @"C:\\CSV.txt";

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string line = lines[i];
        if (line.Contains(","))
        {
            var split = line.Split(',');
            if (split[1].Contains("34"))
            {
                split[1] = "100";
                line = string.Join(",", split);
            }
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\\CSV.txt", lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string str;
        string PID;
        string PN;
        string UP;
        string DIS;
        string STK;
        string CSVFilePathName = @"C:\admin.csv";
        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
        File.Delete(CSVFilePathName);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(CSVFilePathName", true);

            PID = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0])).Text;
            PN = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
            UP = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
            DIS = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
            STK = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text;
        foreach (string li in Lines)
        {
            string[] Fields = li.Split(',');
            if(PID==Fields[0])
            {                                                                     
                str = PID + "," + PN + "," + UP + "," + DIS + "," + STK;                                 
            }
            else
            {
                str = Fields[0] + "," + Fields[1] + "," + Fields[2] + "," + Fields[3] + "," + Fields[4];                 
            }
            sw.WriteLine(str);
        }
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
```

Comment: This is get value from grid and update the .CSV file process. If you guys have any doubt share with me. This is work fine.